# odoo mod_wsgi schedulers not working

Tags: python, apache, deployment, odoo, mod-wsgi

When I deploy openerp/odoo using mod_wsgi, I found my schedulers stop working, can any one help how can I get my cron/schedulers working. If I deploy it using mod_proxy it will solve the issue but I want to deploy using mod_wsgi.

Answer (score 0):

The schedulers don't work when running through wsgi because your Odoo instances are just workers.  AFAIK you just run a standalone instance on a 127.0.0.1 port and it runs your scheduled tasks.